# Rendered result is blank

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

So I animated this cube,changed the render settings a bit and put it for render. But the render is blank. How do I make everything visible in the render? Here is the file download link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VHFGgjWzLmmsA2DxNGYQB2Ahhk1Kg8dt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: In the Viewport Shading panel, you need to reactivate Scene Lights and Scene World and you will see that for the moment you have no light and no world

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.